# Use of "Could" vs "Would" for polite request

Tags: modal-verbs

Do following two lines can be used interchangeably for making a polite request.If not,why?

"Could you pass me the salt?"

"Would you pass me the salt?"

Answer (score 1):

"Could" and "Would" do technically have different meanings, but in the case of a polite request, they are **100% interchangeable**.

Personally, I always follow ***could you*** and ***would you*** with ***please***, even if my politeness is not sincere.

> ***Could you please pass the salt?***
>
> ***Would you please stop using my salt?!***